# Calendar instance not working

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

Trying to print the time in different time zones using `GregorianCalendar` using the code below but does not work. Any ideas why?

`GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST")).getTime()`. It prints the time as per my timezone and not at PST.

Answer (score 1):

By design java.util.Date would be initialized by the UTC milliseconds since the epoch and therefore not take timezones into account. The following code would generate :

```
    Calendar pstCalendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
    Calendar defCalendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());

    // Same values here :
    System.out.println(pstCalendar.getTime());
    System.out.println(defCalendar.getTime());

    // Different values here :
    System.out.println(pstCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    System.out.println(defCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

A solution would be to not use getTime method directly but take Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET into account and take the diff before converting into a date object:

```
    Date d = new Date();

    // Default time :
    System.out.println(d);

    d.setTime(d.getTime() + pstCalendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET));

    // Time after applying offset
    System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: To change the meaning of `java.util.Date.getTime()` to *local* millis is really a very bad design idea. You are coding in opposition to the spec meaning ignoring the spec of that class. It is just a dirty hack.

Answer (score 1):

[Calendar#getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()) -
Returns a Date object representing this Calendar's time value (millisecond offset from the Epoch.To be precise the value within a java.util.Date is the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, which occurred at midnight January 1st 1970, UTC. and java.util.Date is has no specific time zone.

on the other hand you can achieve what you are trying to do in this way also

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid j.u.Calendar

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome and outmoded. Avoid them. Instead use Joda-Time or the java.time package in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time).

Unlike j.u.Date, a date-time object in these other two libraries know their own assigned time zone.

## Joda-Time

Some example code in Joda-Time 2.5. Working with time zones becomes elementary when using Joda-Time.

```
DateTime dateTimeDefaultZone = DateTime.now(); // The JVM’s current default time zone assigned. I recommend always specifying a zone instead of implicitly relying on default.
DateTime dateTimeLosAngeles = dateTimeDefaultZone.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Los_Angeles" ) );
DateTime dateatimeUtc = dateTimeDefaultZone.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime dateTimeKolkata = dateTimeDefaultZone.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
```

## Time Zone Names

Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Avoid those 3 or 4 letter codes as they are neither standardized nor unique, and they confuse the Daylight Saving Time problem further.